# Що означає "розтікатись мислями по древу"?

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

"*Розтікатися мислями по древу* —  даний фразеологізм викликав у мене багато запитань. У [фразеологічному словнику](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53408/361102.html) є пояснення цього вислову, але наскільки я зрозуміла він має дещо негативне значення  — довго, інколи беззмістовно розмірковувати над чимось. Та переглянувши приклади, де зустрічається даний вираз, побачила уривок із "Слово про Ігорів похід":
  «…Боян був віщим, а якщо хотів пісню творити, то розтікався мислію по древу, сірим вовком по землі, сизим орлом під хмарами».
Вище зазначене тлумачення фразеологізму в даному випадку, мені здається, не дуже вдале. Чи може тут він означає щось інше? Можливо цей фразеологізм має позитивне значення?

Comment: Ще в одному джерелі зустріла, що в даному прикладі "розтікатися мислію по древу" слово "мислію" означає білку. Тепер взагалі незрозуміло значення цього виразу.

Comment: Не «„мыслію“ означає білку», а припускають, що там замість «мыслію» має бути «мысію» (від «мысь» — білка/вивірка). Адже ми маємо не оригінал XII ст, а лише результати ручного переписування ([1](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl30.htm) (зліва), [2](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl32.htm)), при якому можливі помилки чи «виправлення» переписувачем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [зазначеному в іншій відповіді](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3561) відео Авраменко **частково помиляється**.

Вираз «розтікатися мислями/мислю/мислію по д(е)реву» справді походить із «Слова о полку Ігоревім» (див., наприклад, с. 1 у [катерининської копії](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl32.htm) кінця XVIII ст. або с. 3 у [виданні 1800 року](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl30.htm)). І в сучасній мові він справді набув значення «бути занадто багатослівним» (що найімовірніше не відповідає його початковому значенню, де це було позитивною оцінкою Бояна).

Але немає інформації про те, щоб у «давнину мислю називали білку», як це стверджує Авраменко. Натомість:

- Початковою інтерпретацією наприкінці XVIII – на початку XIX століть була буквальна — що мисль у даному випадку означає саме мисль/думку. Наприклад, див. російський переклад на с. 3 у виданні 1800 року. Така інтерпретація потрапила й у багато українських перекладів, зокрема: Михайла Максимовича («[Зараз думкою по древу // Починає він літать](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl04.htm)»), Юрія Федьковича («[буяв лісами, як дума](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl07.htm)»), Івана Франка («[думков // Розпускався по деревах](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl09.htm)»), Панаса Мирного («[Розпускаєш свої думки по древу літати](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl11.htm)»), Костянтина Зіньківського («[Розкидував думки по древу](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl15.htm)»), Василя Щурата («[по дереву гадки-мислі](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl16.htm)») тощо.
- Деяким перекладачам таке сусідство думки з вовком і орлом не подобалося і вони заміняли слово «мисль» на довільну тварину: солов'я, рись тощо.
- У 1854 году Миколай Корелкін припустив, що «мыслію» у фразі «растѣкашеся мыслію по древу» є опискою, а натомість в оригіналі мало бути «мысію» (тобто «миссю» — від «мись»). При цьому він зазначав, що в Опочецькому повіті Псковської губернії Російської імперії на той момент часу досі миссю називали білку (вивірку). Більшість дослідників із ним погодилася; така інтерпретація потрапила наприклад, і в український переклад Володимира Кендзерського («[То векшею розганявся до древу](http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl10.htm)»).

Тобто: **не «мисль» позначає (чи позначало колись) білку, а «мись» позначає білку** (а під час переписування переписувач зробив одрук чи навмисну спробу виправлення).

Пов'язування ж мисливства з білками (або в інтерпретації Авраменка з цього відео, або у варіанти «мисливство ← мис(о)ловство ← ловля мисей (білок)», що теж популярна в інтернеті) є радше народною етимологією. Згідно до «Етимологічного словника української мови» в 7 томах слово «мисливство» в українській мові має польське походження (це слово є спільним для українців, поляків і чехів, але не інших слов'ян). Поляки ж однозначно пов'язують «myśliwy» зі словом «мисль» (див., наприклад, статтю [«myśl»](//pl.wikisource.org/wiki/S%C5%82ownik_etymologiczny_j%C4%99zyka_polskiego/my%C5%9Bl) у      етимологічному словнику Александера Брюкнера). Ані поляки, ані чехи, здається, не називають білок мисями.

Answer (score 3):

О. Авраменко у [Сніданку з 1+1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVqy3SBwFvc) каже про фразеологізм "розтікатися мислю по древу" так:

> Розповідати про щось надто багато; бути багатослівним.

Також він говорить і про його походження саме на прикладі "Слово о полку Ігоревім":

> Мисль = білка. Таким чином, О. Авраменко вважає, що "Боян так майстерно вмів співати, як білка бігає по дереву (ніхто краще неї цього не вміє робити), як вовк бігає по землі, як орел літає під хмарами. Ось звідки мисливець і мисливство. Тобто буквально це людина, яка полює на білку, з якої у давнину шили дорогі шуби. Тому мисливствознавство - це білкознавство".